# what is the cause number of succes imported contact not same with number of found contact in system

Tags: drupal

i have imported contacts.the number is 12124 , 
but when i searh them ( find contacts ), there only 12123 
[image]
[image]

what is the cause number of succes imported contact not same with number of found contact in system
i attached screenshot

civicrm 4.4.11
drupal 7.32

thanks and best regards

Comment: Your search filters on Contact Subtype. Is it possible that one of the imported records is a different Subtype than Donor?

Comment: thanks Nicholai,
when i import them , i select sub contact is donor.
i also try to find , whether there in other type contact, but not found

any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You have 1 duplicate record.  Note that the import counter indicates "created or modified" contacts.  If you change the dedupe settings for the import you'll get a different result for the number of contacts in your database, but the number of records "created or modified" will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a wild guess, but it might be that the counter in the importer simply counts the number of lines processed, and that the first line is the column header line? Should be easy to find out with a trial with 5 lines?

Comment: hi ErikH
when i am try with 5 all is ok,
acctualy i have 12125 rows include header. meaning 12124 is data rows.
i mport these data via sql query not csv,
btw, what do you mean about It is just a wild guess,?

Comment: @henro I mean that I did not investigate this option myself, that it is just an idea of what could be happening :-)

Comment: appreciate @ErikH :)